# Removing a rafter

Tags: roof, attic, extension

I have a small opening between my main loft space and the loft space of my extension (I have to turn sideways to get between the loft spaces). I wish to create a larger connection between loft spaces by removing a rafter that supports the main roof section. what do I need to do to prevent sagging of the roof

Comment: A picture of what you want to change might help.  Usually a 'rafter' is the piece of wood, that the roof deck is right above.  You might want to change a support post that might be easier to do, but still requires an engineer to check.

Comment: Are you certain they are _rafters_ and they're not _trusses_? Cutting trusses takes even more care and engineering than cutting rafters. Neither is a great idea for a novice.

Answer (score 2):

- Either learn to live without what you want (this is likely run to
  serious money, either in the "to do it right" or "the consequeces of
  doing it wrong" direction)
- Or consult (as in pay a consulting fee) an engineer licensed to
  practice in your area to determine a solution, and then you can
  dertmine if you can actually afford that solution. You pay the engineer either way...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is strengthen the rafters either side of the one you want to remove and install other supports for the, now unsupported, roof between them.

Consult a framing manual, (treat it as installing a window in a roof) or if that proves fruitless an engineer.